# Running two webservers in Linux box - Apache2 and OPA

Tags: web-server, lamp

I have a linux box running ubuntu with LAMP. I'm planning to add opa (http://opalang.org) on the same server. According to opa documentation it will run through port 8080 by default. Is there a way to make both run on localhost without specifying any port?

For example:

```
1. http://localhost/php_project/index.php
2. http://localhost/opa_project/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible, they will both bind to a certain Port, so if you use 8080 and Apache2 uses this port as well (it's the backup http port), then your OPA will not be able to use it, thus not getting any requests through.

If you want both running, you can however configure Apache2 to pass on the request to OPA (mod_proxy) or redirect automatically to the OPA port.